# Git - Push current Heroku repo to a remote github repo

Tags: git, heroku, github, version-control

I have a project set up with a heroku Git repository and after making some new changes on a new branch I want to push this branch and the diff between my last Heroku commit to the Github repo.

How would I go about doing this so I can engage in a work flow of pushing to Heroku and to Github when specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general solution, you add github as an additional repo to your project. At this point heroku is your `origin` repo, so let's say github is your `alternate` repo.

You create a new repo in your github account, let's say

```
git@github.com:AdamBronfin/myproject.git
```

Then you add it to your working copy

```
git remote add alternate git@github.com:AdamBronfin/myproject.git
```

Then, whenever you want to sync from heroku to github, you do

```
git pull origin master
git push alternate master
```

in this example I used the master branch, but you can do the same with the other branches. As per pushing the diff from your latest commit, that's a bit more specific and you'll have to try for yourself.